# Best Way to Setup a Network of WP Sites?

Tags: multisite, login, domain-mapping

What, in your opinion, is the best way to setup a network of WP sites with a shared login?

- I want users to stay logged in to their account when they switch sites
- I want this to be used with different domains

Comment: Ehm, multisite? I am not sure if this is very basic, or I am missing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is very easy with this plugin: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/ It does cross-domain cookie syncing with all of your sites on one Multisite installation.

I've used this a couple times and it works dandy.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rarst mentioned above, is anything wrong with setting up WordPress as a Multisite see the Codex [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).